# FIFO queue of Multiple Threads for single TCP Socket send request and wait for response

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, queue

So heres my current java implementation:

1. Receive UDP packages from UDP socket using a thread, put the packet into a non-blocking queue.
2. One of 300 threads reads off this non-blocking queue and processes this packet as a request to a Socket connected to a TCP host/port.
3. Wait for the response and return this back to the UDP socket.

This part all works ok, but from analysis of the TCP socket part under high load, i've seen that in random cases it can take around 2-5 seconds for the TCP socket part to complete. Usually this part takes 2-3 ms. My quess is that i'm just hitting the TCP Socket with random thread execution and that i don't have FIFO of thread operation.

Is there a way i could place the 'request' information plus current thread reference (i guess to know which thread to process the 'response') into a FIFO blocking queue to ensure that the oldest thread is processed first to ensure that TCP socket request/response operation takes a minimum amount of time.

Comment: Are the individual threads doing blocking TCP operations?  Or have you arranged them to be nonblocking?  If so, how?

Comment: Why? How do you know that ordering it like that will change the TCP response time? Why does order matter when UDP itself is unordered?

Comment: I hope you have 300 cores in that box.

Comment: @Keith i have the following: toTCPServer.println(message); response = fromTCPServer.readLine(); which blocks until there is a response from the TCP Server.

Comment: @EJP The UDP packets are unordered and connection-less but the threads handling them are blocking at the TCP socket part. I care about getting responses very quickly or else they are deemed failed by the original UDP packet sender.

Comment: @Nikolai i have 2 CPUs each with 6 cores or 24 virtual cores. I'm using java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool. Whats the best number of threads i should use i wonder?

Comment: I still don't understand. The thread that takes the next request from the queue is by definition not blocking on anything, and ready to process a new request, so provided the queue is already ordered by request time, which it naturally will be unless you do something odd, the oldest request is already getting serviced first. I don't see why you need to add thread IDs and all the rest of it to get what already happens to happen; and I don't understand how any of it can ensure that TCP request/response processing takes minimum time. That's up to the TCP server(s) you are talking to.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way i could place the 'request' information plus current thread reference

I would have an `AtomicLong` request-counter that would get incremented for each request.  The counter would then be associated with the UDP socket in a request-map with any other per-request information.  The counter would also be sent over the TCP socket.  The response from the TCP socket would come back with the request-counter and the reader thread would either send the response back over the appropriate UDP socket or schedule it in a thread-pool.

Once you have the request-counter then the TCP socket would be a request/response stream so that they can be sent out of order if necessary.  A thread would be sending requests to the remote server and another thread would be reading responses and scheduling the response back to the UDP client.  You could guarantee FIFO order if necessary but if another response is ready I don't see why it has to wait just because it is out of order.

On the server side you would have a similar reader and writer thread both consuming from work queues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you seek a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) - Here's it's description, with some emphasis from me.

> An unbounded **thread-safe** queue based on linked nodes. This queue orders elements **FIFO (first-in-first-out)**. The **head** of the queue is that element that has been on the **queue the longest time**. The **tail** of the queue is that element that has been on the **queue the shortest time**. New elements are inserted at the tail of the queue, and the queue retrieval operations obtain elements at the head of the queue. A ConcurrentLinkedQueue is an appropriate choice when **many threads will share access to a common collection.** This queue does **not permit null** elements.